# Higher order moments of a multivariate Gaussian rv

Tags: normal-distribution, moments, cumulants

Let $X~N_d(\mu,\Sigma)$ be a multivariate Gaussian random vector.  Is there a convenient formula for each of 
$$
\mu_p\triangleq \mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{i=1}^d |X_i|^p\right],
$$
in terms of $\mu$ and of $\Sigma$?

**Reasoning**
This is true for the univariate case; see [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Moments).  For example, when $d=1$ and $p=3$, then $\mu_p= \mu^3 + 3\mu\sigma^2$.

This is to be distinguished from [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/297313/second-order-moment-of-multivariate-gaussian-bishop-p-83), which consideres the second higher-order moment but defining it via the *outer*  and not *inner* product.

Comment: "or example, when d=1 and p=, then" .... did you intend to up a 3 in there after "p="?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since
$$\mu_p\triangleq \mathbb{E}_{\mu,\sigma}\left[\sum_{i=1}^d |X_i|^p\right]=\sum_{i=1}^d\mathbb{E}_{\mu,\sigma}\left[|X_i|^p\right]$$
the multivariate nature of $X=(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ and in particular the correlations between the $X_i$'s have no relevance. For a Normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$, the moments are connected by the recurrence relation [(Patel & Read, 1986)](https://amzn.to/2T28y91)$$\xi_p\triangleq\mathbb{E}_{\mu,\sigma}[X^p]=\mu\xi_{p-1}+(p-1)\sigma^2\xi_{p-2}$$which provides $\mu_{2q}=\xi_{2q}$. As stated by Wikipedia][2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Moments), the generic absolute moment of order $p>0$ is
$$\mathbb{E}_{\mu,\sigma}\left[|X|^p \right] =\sigma^p 2^{p/2} \frac {\Gamma\left(\frac{1+p} 2\right)}{\sqrt\pi} {}_1F_1\left( -\frac{p}{2}, \frac{1}{2}, -\frac{1}{2} \left( \frac \mu \sigma \right)^2 \right)$$

Comment: Amazing, this is very helpful... but do you have a reference also?  I would need that.  Merci Xi'an

Comment: Nono, for the recurrence relation.